# How to stop this weird thing for limiting word in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Click http://jsfiddle.net/1ybzcppk/8/ to see.
I can successfully limit word enter, but there is a weird thing happening. When you reach the max, the sixth word still show up. If I kept enter, it kept replace the last word. I want nothing show up when it reach the 5th word. Help, appreciate.

JQuery:

```
$("#input").keydown(function(event) {

  var count = $('#test').text();
  var words = count.match(/\S+/g).length;
  if (words >= 5) {
    var trimmed = $('#test').text().split(/\s+/, 5).join(" ");
    // Add a space at the end to keep new typing making new words
    $('#test').text(trimmed + " ");

  }

  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //put input value into div
    var value = $('#input').val();
    $('#test').text($('#test').html() + " " + value);

  }


});
```

CSS:

```
.test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="test">dog</div>
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Comment: If you want nothing to show up after 5 words, then you should do nothing in the `if`.

Comment: Why do you need a fiddle when you have a code snippet here?

Comment: sometime code snippet is not working, but fiddle is working. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Move the enter handler to the else part

```js
$("#input").keydown(function(event) {
  var count = $('#test').text();
  var words = count.match(/\S+/g).length;
  if (words >= 5) {
    var trimmed = $('#test').text().split(/\s+/, 5).join(" ");
    // Add a space at the end to keep new typing making new words
    $('#test').text(trimmed + " ");
  } else if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //put input value into div
    var value = $('#input').val();
    $('#test').text($('#test').html() + " " + value);

  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="test">dog</div>
<input type="text" id="input" />
```